Como faço para mandar e-mail em C# pelo g-mail?
Ola estou usando o metodo para enviar e-mail com c# pelo g-mail...mas nao esta funcionando
        private string MotorEnvioGmail(FilaDeServidor pServidor, FilaDeEnvio pMsg)
    {
        _Loglog = " ";
        // Criando o cliente SMTP com SSL/TLS ativado
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(pServidor.SMTP, int.Parse(pServidor.PortaSMTP)))
        {
            client.EnableSsl = true; // Ativar SSL/TLS
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // Desabilitar credenciais padrão (não recomendado)
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(pServidor.Login, pServidor.Senha);

            // Criando o e-mail
            MailMessage mensagem = new MailMessage();
            try
            {
                mensagem.From = new MailAddress(pServidor.Login);
                mensagem.To.Add(pMsg.Contato);
                mensagem.Subject = pMsg.Assunto.Trim();
                mensagem.Body = pMsg.Mensagem.Trim();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                _Loglog = _Loglog + "Erro ao enviar o e-mail:" + Ex.Message;
                return _Loglog;
            }
            //anexos
            if (pMsg.Anexo.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    mensagem.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(pMsg.Anexo.Trim()));
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    _Loglog = _Loglog + Ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _Loglog = _Loglog + "Não tem anexo vinculado";
            }

            // Enviando o e-mail
            try
            {
                client.Send(mensagem);
                _Loglog = _Loglog + "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _Loglog = _Loglog + "Erro ao enviar o e-mail:" + ex.Message;
            }
        }

        return _Loglog;
    }


Tente assim
private string MotorEnvioGmail(FilaDeServidor pServidor, FilaDeEnvio pMsg)
{
    _Loglog = " ";
    try
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(pServidor.SMTP, int.Parse(pServidor.PortaSMTP)))
        {
            client.EnableSsl = true; // Ativar SSL/TLS
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // Desabilitar credenciais padrão (não recomendado)
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(pServidor.Login, pServidor.Senha);

            // Criando o e-mail
            MailMessage mensagem = new MailMessage();
            mensagem.From = new MailAddress(pServidor.Login);
            mensagem.To.Add(pMsg.Contato);
            mensagem.Subject = pMsg.Assunto.Trim();
            mensagem.Body = pMsg.Mensagem.Trim();
            mensagem.IsBodyHtml = true; // Se o corpo do e-mail estiver em HTML, caso contrário, defina como false

            // Anexos
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pMsg.Anexo))
            {
                try
                {
                    mensagem.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(pMsg.Anexo.Trim()));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _Loglog += "Erro ao adicionar anexo: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _Loglog += "Não tem anexo vinculado.";
            }

            // Enviando o e-mail
            client.Send(mensagem);
            _Loglog += "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
        }
    }
    catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
    {
        _Loglog += "Erro ao enviar o e-mail (SMTP): " + smtpEx.Message;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _Loglog += "Erro ao enviar o e-mail: " + ex.Message;
    }

    return _Loglog;
}


